# Python While Else - URL check

Tags: python, loops, selenium, url

Hi I am trying to make script that goes onto website and then checks websites URL until the URL changes.

```
import easygui
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER.EXE")
driver.get("URL OF SOME WEBSITE")
time.sleep(10)

b = "URL OF SOME WEBSITE"
a = driver.current_url

while a == b:
    a = driver.current_url
else:
    easygui.msgbox ("URL changed")
```

The problem is with the loop and I don't understand what is wrong there :-(

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison.

Comment: Thank you for advice now i am getting one less error :D                              I am getting syntax error on Else: and on a = driver.current_url

Comment: you're using one equal for comparison while you should use double equal. don't forget the indentation as well.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly is wrong with your loop?

Comment: I didnt know about Python and how Tabulators and Spaces works :-D but for now i think i get it :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Python is the indentation important, and the comparision operator is `==`.

So instead of

```
while a = b:
a = driver.current_url
else:
easygui.msgbox ("URL changed")
```

use

```
while a == b:
    a = driver.current_url
else:
    easygui.msgbox ("URL changed")
```

Comment: `while a = b` is a `SyntaxError`.